# Why is my $_FILES empty given the following code?

Tags: javascript, php, vue.js

In my frontend PHP page I have a simple upload file input object:

```
<input type="file" v-on:change="fileAdded">
```

My fileAdded function within my JS file simply takes the event object (e) and grabs the file in order to obtain other information regarding the file itself:

```
if (e.target.files !== undefined) {
    v.data_file = e.target.files[0]
}
```

I then put the data file and a request code into a fetch statement to my backend:

```
fetch("pages/gp/gpBackend.php", {
    method: "POST",
    body: v.form_data_obj
})
```

Within my backend php page I use the $_FILES array to grab information like the filename and extension of the file to then pass along to a python script that I have which will unpack the data in the file itself.

During this phase of operation of my webpage, everything works fine, I send the response back to my frontend, handle the data accordingly and move on.

The rest of my frontend requires the user to input certain data before submitting a second post back to my backend with a different request code.

In that instance I send another FormObject with all the needed data to my backend in the same manner I did with my file upload POST. However this time my $_FILES is now empty and I cannot access the file name or extension of the file I uploaded earlier.

I cannot seem to find out why this is the case? I have a near identical set up on another frontend/backend php page I have for the same site that through both POSTS maintains the files in $_FILES to be used however often it is needed. But for this page, without me being able to tell the difference, when I POST another request to my backend the second time $_FILES is empty.

I can provide any additional details that would be needed to answer this question so please let me know. I do know it is not a file size issue as not only do I have the .ini configured for an admin (me) set file size limit, but the file I'm currently using as an example during development is significantly smaller than the max file size on my web server.

Thank you for any help anyone can provide!

Comment: One sign that could point towards the problem is this:

I decided to go ahead and send the temporary filename and extension back through the POST to my Javascript post via the Fetch response and save that information locally. From there I added it to my second POST object's body and attempted to use them as my arguments since $_FILES was empty. I got an error that no such file or directory exists for my temporary filename. I checked my tmp folder on my web server and sure enough it isn't there. This same method works for my second page so why is the temp file being deleted this time?

Answer (score 0):

PHP $_FILE must serve with a  with enctype as this way.

```
<form action="upload.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
```

Hope this help: https://www.w3schools.com/php/php_file_upload.asp

Comment: Hello Lukas, 

I've seen this answer on several forums but the issue is that I'm using javascript/Vue to handle the post to my backend, not a form on my front end. On my other webpage this fetch method works perfectly:

            fetch("pages/cc/ccBackend.php", {
                method: "POST",
                body: v.form_data_obj
            })